# "***Error*** bash: line 1: 7854 Killed" in java

Tags: java

I am trying to solve the following USACO practice problem:

> Is Friday the 13th really an unusual event?
>
> That is, does the 13th of the month land on a Friday less often than on any other day of the week? To answer this question, write a program that will compute the frequency that the 13th of each month lands on Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, and Saturday over a given period of N years. The time period to test will be from January 1, 1900 to December 31, 1900+N-1 for a given number of years, N. N is non-negative and will not exceed 400.
>
> There are few facts you need to know before you can solve this problem:
>
> - January 1, 1900 was on a Monday.
> - Thirty days has September, April, June, and November, all the rest have 31 >except for February which has 28 except in leap years when it has 29.
> - Every year evenly divisible by 4 is a leap year (1992 = 4*498 so 1992 will >be a leap year, but the year 1990 is not a leap year)
> - The rule above does not hold for century years. Century years divisible by >400 are leap years, all other are not. Thus, the century years 1700, 1800, >1900 and 2100 are not leap years, but 2000 is a leap year.
>
> Do not use any built-in date functions in your computer language.
>
> Don’t just precompute the answers, either, please.

I coded a solution which seems to work for most of the test cases, but for one test case the following error appears:

```
***Error***
bash: line 1:  7854 Killed              java -Xms16m -Xss16m -Xmx32m friday
```

This is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class friday
{
    static int day = 1;
    static  int month = 1;
    static int year = 1900;
    static int[] days = new int[7];
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    int num;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    num = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
    counter(num);
    for (int i=0; i<7; i++)
    {
    System.out.print(days[i]+ " ");
    }
 }
 public static void counter(int n)
 {
     int index=2;
     days[2]=1;
     while (year<1900+n)
    {
        day++;
        index++;
        if (index>6)
        index=0;
        if (day==29 && (year % 4!=0 ^ year % 100==0) && month==2)
        incrementmonth();
        if (day==31 && (month==4 || month==6 || month==9 || month==11))
        incrementmonth();
        if (day==32 && (month==1 || month==3 || month==5 || month==7 || month==8 || month==10 || month==12))
        incrementmonth();
        if (day==13)
        days[index]++;
    }
    days[2]--;
 }
 public static void incrementmonth()
 {
     day=1;
     month++;
     if (month>12)
     {
         month=1;
         year++;
     }
 }
}
```

My code works for the test cases 1 and 2, but for the test case of 5 as N, it outputs the error instead of an integer result. The expected output is 9 9 7 9 9 8 9. If anyone could help me figure out the problem with my code, it would be very much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: @JustinKSU and what is `friday` then?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! 
Please take the [tour](/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). 
Please add the **complete error message** and a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](/help/mcve) including test data.

Comment: 9 9 7 9 9 8 9 is the expected output of 5 @ModusTollens Test case 5 is if the input is 5

Comment: a 16 MB heap is very small but a 16 MB stack is pretty large by comparison.

Comment: Please edit this information into the question, so if anybody reads it, will know it right away, and does not need to read through the comments.

Comment: alright i did the changes